Sign of components of spinor spherical harmonics
In Bjorken and Drell's text on relativistic QFT, the spinor spherical harmonics for a spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particle with orbital angular momentum $\ell$ are given as $$\chi_{j,m}=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{\frac{\ell+\frac{1}{2}+m}{2\ell+1}}Y_{\ell}^{m-\frac{1}{2}} \\ -\sqrt{\frac{\ell+\frac{1}{2}-m}{2\ell+1}}Y_{\ell}^{m+\frac{1}{2}} \end{bmatrix}$$ for $j=\ell-\frac{1}{2}$. They say they are using the convention that $$\bar{Y}_{\ell}^{m}=(-1)^m Y_{\ell}^{-m} .$$ If I am correct, this uses the Condon Shortly phase convention. With the CS phase convention, shouldn't the spin $+\frac{1}{2}$ component should be negative?. I am unsure how we show in this case that the the spin $-\frac{1}{2}$ component is negative. Is this arbitrary or can it be shown that with this convention, the spin $-\frac{1}{2}$ component MUST be negative?
